# variance-covariance matrix in R - Weibull survival curve

Tags: r, covariance, survival-analysis, weibull

A simple doubt:

Can I use values from

```
vcov(ajust)
```

directly? Or is it needed a kind of transformation?

I mean, at a Weibull model,

```
vcov(ajust)[1,1]
```

gives me directly the variance of shape parameter or I need to do some more calculation?

Answer (score 0):

the variance is marked in red. the transformation is correct, row1, column1 gives the variance. you do not need to do any further calculation.

Comment: Their is a transformation for the covariance matrix; (-1)^j+m (A)^n = summation a^mn (bij); m>n; m=i+j, A=Bij. The transformation is the sum of the squared covariance matrix.